# EasyUI treegrid collapseAll initially

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-easyui

I have used the below example to populate a hierarchical structure.

http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/treegrid.php

When initially loaded, the tree is all expanded. IS there any setting which I am missing to load the tree initially all collapsed. I have tried "state: 'closed' in the data-options but it is not working.

Comment: please provide your code

Answer (score 0):

If you used the "convert" filter, you can add the **state** property to your node

```
while(toDo.length){
    var node = toDo.shift();    // the parent node
    // get the children nodes
    for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
        var row = rows[i];
        if (row.parentId == node.id){
            var child = {id:row.id,text:row.name, state:'closed'};
            if (node.children){
                node.children.push(child);
            } else {
                node.children = [child];
            }
            toDo.push(child);
        }
    }
}
```